# Generating random permutation with N cycle

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, random, permutation-cycles

Suppose we have integer list from 1 to N. I am interested in generating random permutations such that its cycle notation has only one N cycle.

> What algorithms are known to generate random N-cycle permutations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canonical method to generate such a random permutation, which is termed *cyclic*, is [Sattolo's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Sattolo's_algorithm), a variant of the Fisher–Yates shuffle to generate a random general permutation. Its description is terrifically simple:

> Swap the last unprocessed element of the list with a random element $a$ that lies strictly before it. Mark $a$ as processed.

Comment: BTW, Do you know the count of such N-cycle permutations?

Comment: @MohammadAl-Turkistany $(N-1)!$